# Как "пронумеровать" буквы в слове относительно алфавита

Tags: java

Нужно написать метод, генерирующую `int[]`, каждое значение которого будет соответствовать позиции буквы конкретного слова (`String`, будем передавать в этот метод) относительно алфавита, т.е. нужно получить что-то в таком духе:

```
SOMEWORDS | 743295618
STAR | 3412
LETTER | 314526
```

`D` — Первая буква (относительно алфавита) в слове → `_ _ _ _ _ _ _ 1 _`
 
`E` — вторая → `_ _ _ 2 _ _ _ 1 _`  
`M` — третья → `_ _ 3 2 _ _ _ 1 _`  
и т.д.

Если буквы повторяются, то первой нумеруется та, которая первая входит в слово.

В представленном ниже коде я попытался избавиться от повторяющихся символов и отсортировать строку (подсказали на enSO), но, сделав это, я понял, что ничего не понимаю и не знаю что делать дальше:

```
TreeSet<Character> keyTreeSet = new TreeSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < keywordArray.length; i++) {
    keyTreeSet.add(keyword.charAt(i));
}
Iterator iterator;
iterator = keyTreeSet.iterator();
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    s.append(iterator.next());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение "в лоб", работающее за `O(n^2)`.
`N` раз (где `N` - длина строки) проходим по строке и ищем символ с минимальным кодом среди ещё не использованных (для которых в массиве не сохранено значение), после чего сохраняем в массиве номер итерации в ячейке, индекс которой совпадает с индексом найденного символа с минимальным кодом:

```
private static int[] getNumbers(String str)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[str.length()];
    for (int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int indexOfMin = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++)
        {
            if (numbers[j] == 0)
            {
                int c = (int)str.charAt(j);
                if (c < min)
                {
                    min = c;
                    indexOfMin = j;
                }
            }
        }
        numbers[indexOfMin] = i;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Оно работает... Невероятно! Я вам крайне признателен!

Comment: @KirillDemidov на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, то не забудьте отметить его как правильный (галочка слева от ответа). Решение, на самом деле, весьма простое. Возможно, существуют более хитрые решения.